# Updating an item in Mongoose not working --- save is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making a very simple app to practice CRUD operations using Node, MongoDb, and Mongoose to handle my database, and I am getting stuck on the update portion of it.

Here is my code:

```
// update
app.patch('/api/update', async (req, res) => {
  const { product, price } = req.body;
  try {
    let productToBeUpdated = await Product.find({ product: product });
    productToBeUpdated.price = price;
    productToBeUpdated.save();
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ status: 'failed, no such product' });
    console.error(err);
  }

  res.json({ status: 'successfully updated' });
});
```

I am expecting `Product.find({ product: product })` to retrieve any product that matches the product sent by `req.body.product`. And then I want to update that product's price. And then I want to save the updated product to the database. However I'm getting an error: `productToBeUpdated.save is not a function`

How do I get mongoose to save the change to the database?

Comment: Can you do `Product.findOne({ product: product })`?  Does it behave differently then?

Comment: I ask this because in pure mongodb, `find()` will return a cursor to loop over all elements found, while `findOne()` will return just one matching element.

Comment: There's an API for what you want to do; try [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) as `await Product.findOneAndUpdate({ product }, { price })`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are running into is that `productToBeUpdated` in this case would be an array (which does not have a `save` method by default); as returned by [Model.find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find).

Assuming your logic that you want to update all matches of `product`:

> I am expecting Product.find({ product: product }) to retrieve any product that matches the product sent by req.body.product.

To achieve your logic we can use [Model.updateMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany):

```js
const result = await Product.updateMany({ product }, { price });
```